# Magento payments and transactions, actual working pattern?

Tags: magento, payment

I am working on an exportation module for accountancy datas, those 2 questions about payments are giving me troubles :

- Is it possible for an order to have multiple payments related to it ?
  It seems to be the case in the database, but since I'm working on localhost for dev, I can't make real payments happen for testing.
  For example, Order1 is 170$, and it is associated with Payment1 100$ and Payment2 70$ in SALES_FLAT_ORDER_PAYMENT table.
- Also, how are transactions related to payments ?
  In the database it seems that one payment can have multiple transactions associated. Do these transactions add up in the payment value ?

As far as I searched, Magento can behave in such many ways it's hard to get clear and generic informations from the system (for accountancy).

Comment: Did you find any more info on this?